# nomenclature in elsevier latex template

Tags: templates, latex, terminology, mbox

I got some trouble with nomenclature in Elsevier template.  I followed [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252118/how-to-add-nomenclature-in-elsarticle-2-column-format-through-texmaker) instruction proposed by delrocco.
and now when I wrote the \nomenclature command I got nothing (the box is empty)(please see the attached file). I do not know I must use tabular environment in the middle of the table* environment or use \nomenclature command. When I use tabular environment, I have columns that with different size (the fourth column go out of the box)(the proposed instruction needs making some change in template). I  do not know it is the best solution or not. Also when I use the other solution with \mbox commant i received the error relates to the not proper for two column.  I m confused.
I really appreciate  any help

```
%\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\documentclass[3p,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{framed} % Framing content%@@@

\usepackage{multicol} % Multiple columns environment

\usepackage{nomencl} % Nomenclature package

\makenomenclature

\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parskip} % Baseline skip between items%@@@

\renewcommand*\nompreamble{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\renewcommand*\nompostamble{\end{multicols}}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature


\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\begin{abstract}
    
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
    %\texttt{elsarticle.cls}\sep \LaTeX\sep Elsevier \sep template
    %\MSC[2010] 00-01\sep  99-00
    \texttt{MMMMr}
    %\MSC[2010] 00-01\sep  99-00
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}

\begin{table*}[!t]   %@@@ for nomenculture
    
    \begin{framed}
        
        \nomenclature{$abbreviation$}{explanation for the abbreviation}
       \nomenclature{\(c\)}{Speed of light in a vacuum}
        \nomenclature{\(h\)}{Planck constant}
        \printnomenclature
        
    \end{framed}
    
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```